# Replace a specific column characters in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named `CLIENT` with 3 columns (`fname,lname,city`).

I want to select all 3 columns but when `lname = 'John'` I want to show `'*****'` instead of the actual city

Comment: I would rather do a if statement using the server side language. Example, in php `if($row['lname']==="John"){echo "***"}else{echo $row['lname']}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select fname,lname, (case when lname = 'John' then '*****' else city end) as city
from CLIENT
```

try this query.